# Homeomorphism between upper closed hemisphere and disk.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $H^2$ be the closed upper hemisphere, that is $$H^2=\big\{(x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^3)\;|\;x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\ge0\big\},$$
and let $D^2$ be the closed unit disk $$D^2=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2)\;|\;x^2+y^2=1\big\}.$$

On $H^2$ , define an equivalence relation $\sim$ by identifying the antipodal points on the
equator:
$$(x, y, 0)\sim(−x, −y, 0),\quad x^2 + y^2 = 1.$$
On $D^2$ , define an equivalence relation $\sim$ by identifying the antipodal points on the boundary circle:
$$(x, y) \sim (−x, −y),\quad x^2 + y^2 = 1.$$

> **I must prove that** $$H^2/\sim\;\simeq D^2/\sim.$$

The space $D^2$ and $H^2$ are homeomorphic to each other via the continuous map $\varphi\colon H^2\to D^2$, $\varphi(x, y, z)=(x, y)$, and its inverse
$\psi\colon D^2\to H^2$ , $\psi(x, y) = \big(x, y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\big)$. Note that if $\pi_1\colon H^2\to H^2/\sim$ and $\pi_2\colon D^2\to D^2/\sim$ are the projection map, then exists the following commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    H^2 @>\varphi>> D^2\\
    @V \pi_1 V V @VV \pi_2 V\\
    H^2/\sim @>>\overline{\varphi}> D^2/\sim
\end{CD}

indeed the map $(\pi_2\circ\varphi)\colon H^2\to D^2/\sim$ is constant on each equivalence class of $H^2/\sim$, therefore it induces a map $\overline{\varphi}\colon H^2/\sim\to D^2/\sim$ by $$\overline{\varphi}\big([(x,y,z)]\big)=\pi_2\circ\varphi(x,y,z)=\pi_2(x,y)=[(x,y)],\;\text{for}\; (x,y,z)\in H^2.$$ The map $\overline{\varphi}$ is continuos, since $\pi_2\circ \varphi$ is continuos.

Similarly, exists the following commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    D^2 @>\psi>> H^2\\
    @V \pi_2 V V @VV \pi_1 V\\
    D^2/\sim @>>\overline{\psi}> H^2/\sim
\end{CD}

indeed the map $(\pi_1\circ\psi)\colon D^2\to H^2/\sim$ is constant on each equivalence class of $D^2/\sim$, therefore it induces a map $\overline{\psi}\colon D^2/\sim\to H^2/\sim$ by $$\overline{\psi}\big([(x,y)]\big)=\pi_1\circ\psi(x,y)=\pi_1(x,y,z)=[(x,y,z)],\;\text{for}\; (x,y)\in D^2.$$
The map $\overline{\psi}$ is continuos, since $\pi_1\circ \psi$ is continuos. It remains to show that $\overline{\varphi}$ and $\overline{\psi}$ are the inverse of the other. Therefore, $$\overline{\varphi}\circ\overline{\psi}\big([(x,y)]\big)=\overline{\varphi}\big([(x,y,z)]\big)=[(x,y)],$$ and

$$\overline{\psi}\circ\overline{\varphi}\big([(x,y,z)]\big)=\overline{\psi}\big([(x,y)]\big)=[(x,y,z)].$$

> **Question.** Is this procedure correct? If I could have shown the result more immediately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, the projection $\varphi : H^2 \to D^2, \varphi (x,y,z) = (x,y)$, is a homeomorphism. You have $p \sim p'$ in $H^2$ if and only if $\varphi (p) \sim \varphi (p')$ in $D^2$. It is therefore **obvious** that $\varphi$ induces a homeomorphism $\tilde{\varphi} : H^2/\sim \quad \to D^2/\sim, \tilde{\varphi}[p]) = [\varphi(p)]$.

But of course, your proof is correct.

Comment: @PaulFrostThanks for your answer. The fact that $\overline{\varphi}$ is a homeomorphism from which properties can be deduced?

Comment: If you have spaces $X,Y,Z$ with equivalence relations $\sim_X, \sim_Y,\sim_Z$ and maps $f : X \to Y, g : Y \to Z$ such that $x \sim_X x'$ implies $f(x) \sim_Y f(x')$ and $y \sim_Y y'$ implies $g(y) \sim_Z g(y')$, then you get induced maps $\tilde{f} : X/\sim_X \quad \to Y/\sim_Y$, $\tilde{g} : Y/\sim_Y \quad \to Z/\sim_Z$ and $\widetilde{gf} :  X/\sim_X \quad \to Z/\sim_Z$ satisfying $\widetilde{gf} = \tilde{g} \tilde{f}$. Apply this to $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$  and note that $\widetilde{id} = id$. This is what you have done explicitly, but I think it is obvious.

Comment: The last question: let $X$ and $Y$ be topological space and $\sim_X$, $\sim_Y$ the corresponding equivalence relations. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ an homeomorphism. Is it true or false that if $x\sim_X y$, then $f(x)\sim_Y f(y)$? If it is true, then what we have said is obvious for this reason.

Comment: If we are *given* equivalence relations $\sim_X, \sim_Y$, there is no reason why *any* homeomorphism $f$ should have the property that $x \sim_X x'$ implies $f(x) \sim_Y f(x')$. However, your special $\varphi$ has the property that $x \sim x'$ if and only $\varphi(x) \sim \varphi(x')$.