# Proving two sets are homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, solution-verification, geometric-topology

> Define $S^2:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=1\text{ and }z\ge 0\}$, and $T:=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2:u^2+v^2\le 1\}$. Prove we have the homeomorphism \begin{equation}S^2\cong T,\end{equation} where $S^2$ is equipped with the standard topology and $T$ equipped with the subspace topology inherited from $T$.

Idea: By the definition of homeomorphism, we need to find some function $f:S^2\to T$ whereby $f$ is bicontinuous and bijective. Clearly $S^2$ is the unit sphere, and $T$ is the unit disk. So perhaps we can think of projecting from the sphere to the disk; the way in which to do this is not immediate though. Intuitively we can do this geometrically, by simply taking a point on the sphere's surface and projecting it vertically downwards to a unique point on the disk, but it's not obvious to me how to produce an explicit such homeomorphism. (Of course, this ought to be a homemorphism as it is clearly bijective and bicontinuous).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homeomorphism between upper closed hemisphere and disk.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197127/homeomorphism-between-upper-closed-hemisphere-and-disk)

Comment: @LewisMacRae unfortunately not, as it uses techniques far more advanced than I understand... also the disk in that question has $u^2+v^2=1$ as opposed to simply $u^2+v^2\le 1$.

Comment: That is a typo; $u^2 + v^2 \leq 1$ is meant. As stated in the linked question, your "$S^2$" and $T$ are homeomorphic via the map $\varphi(x, y, z) = (x, y)$ and its inverse $\psi(x, y) = (x, y, \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just project. Consider $S^2_+\ni(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y)\in T$. This is a restriction and corestriction of projection, and we know projection is continuous, so this map is continuous.

Moreover, this map is surjective. That's clear: given $(x,y)\in T$, $z:=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ exists as a positive real number and $(x,y,z)\in S^2_+$, so $(x,y)$ is the image of $(x,y,z)$. Injectivity is similarly seen.

I leave it to you to rigorously conclude this map is a homeomorphism. Hint: maps from compact to Hausdorff spaces have a nice property... EDIT: or much more easily, just specify the inverse explicitly (as above). It is not hard to check the inverse is continuous.

Fwiw this is bad notation to call the space $S^2$, actually this space is not homeomorphic to $S^2$ - the unit sphere - so as a *hemi*sphere I would rather call it $S^2_+$ or something like that.

Comment: Having already written most of the formula for the continuous inverse function, namely the function $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$, applying the theorem on compact Hausdorff spaces seems like overkill.

Comment: @LeeMosher Fair enough. I just like that theorem a lot, it makes checking things are homeomorphisms much less taxing in general

Answer (score 1):

First, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ implies $x^2+y^2=1-z^2$ and since $z$ is positive we have $0 \leq z \leq 1$ as $x^2 + y^2 \geq 0$. Furthermore we partition $T$ into circles by radius of the form $u^2+v^2=1-t$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$. We can now take advantage of the fact that $t \rightarrow z^2$ is a continuous bijection on $[0,1]$ with continuous inverse $z \rightarrow \sqrt{t}$ to provide a homeomorphism between the two spaces.